# Adding Google Analytics to React

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, react-ga

I am trying to add Google Analytics to a React Web Application.

I know how to do it in HTML/CSS/JS sites and I have integrated it in an AngularJS app too. But, I'm not quite sure how to go about it when it comes to react.

With HTML/CSS/JS, I had just added it to every single page.

What I had done with AngularJS was adding GTM and GA script to index.html and added UA-labels to the HTML divs (and buttons) to get clicks.

**How can I do that with React?**

Please help!

Comment: Note that `react-ga` only works with Universal Analytics, whereas new Google Analytics properties are GA4 properties by default. https://stackoverflow.com/q/64623059/9154668

Answer (score 124, accepted):

**Update: August 2023**
The old Package `react-ga` is now archived since it doesn't support Google Analytics version 4.
There's a new package named [`react-ga4`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ga4).
Add it by running:
`npm i react-ga4`

**Initialization**

```js
import ReactGA from "react-ga4";

ReactGA.initialize("your GA measurement id");
```

**To report page view:**

```js
ReactGA.send({ hitType: "pageview", page: "/my-path", title: "Custom Title" });
```

**To report custom event:**

```js
ReactGA.event({
  category: "your category",
  action: "your action",
  label: "your label", // optional
  value: 99, // optional, must be a number
  nonInteraction: true, // optional, true/false
  transport: "xhr", // optional, beacon/xhr/image
});
```

**Update: Feb 2019**
As I saw that this question is being searched a lot, I decided to expand my explanation.
To add Google Analytics to React, I recommend using React-GA.
Add by running:
`npm install react-ga --save`

**Initialization:**
In a root component, initialize by running:

```
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
ReactGA.initialize('Your Unique ID');
```

**To report page view:**

```
ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
```

**To report custom event:**

```
ReactGA.event({
  category: 'User',
  action: 'Sent message'
});
```

More instructions can be found in the [github repo](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga)

---

The best practice for this IMO is using react-ga.
Have a look at the [github rep](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga)

Comment: I agree, I'm using it with react-ga package.

Note that you should use ReactGA.set method to trigger following pageviews.

Comment: Yeah, I checked out react-ga before posting this. Is there no other way? Also, how would I get clicks?

Comment: You can get them by using event. Have a look here: https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga#reactgaeventargs

Comment: Ended up using react-ga and it works great. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Is there any way to use ReactGA.initiliaze(trackid) by fetching the trackid from a response. I use a function for returning ReactGA.initiliaze(trackid) when trackid is defined but i get an error that cannot read property parentNode of udefined

Comment: why not just call `ReactGA.initialize(trackid)` once you have an id? after you receive the id from the server

Comment: Can we use ReactGA on multiple pages and track page views?

Comment: @ReemaParakh Sure. Just call `ReactGA.pageview('your/page');`

Comment: If you use `react-router` It seems easiest to me to put this integration in where you set up your routes: `<Route path="/myroute" render={props => { ReactGA.pageview(props.location.pathname); return <MyRoute />; }} />`

Comment: @alaiacano, You can definitely  do that, just don't forget to pass the props to your component..

Comment: where in the root component?

Comment: @s2t2 what do you mean? can you elaborate?

Comment: @MatanBobi nevermind, I figured it out: init at the top (above component class definition), and you log page views from componentDidMount

Comment: Why not just add an HTML snippet provided by Google Analytics to the index.html file ?

Comment: @Prateek, you can do it, as other answers suggest.. But I believe in encapsulating this and just getting the functionality.

Comment: To report page views do you need to add ```ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);``` to each page or just at the root?

Comment: @SamHeyman you'll need to do that whenever a route changes so you can either do that on the `useEffect` after the first mount of a page component or catch a route change in a generic function. Whatever you choose :)

Comment: I have this snippet my colleague provided me:
<!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=Unique ID"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'Unique ID');
</script>

Is that the same as what you are doing?

Comment: @KenRusselSy Behind the scenes, that's probably what react-ga are doing, but they give you a nicer API and handle the script injection too. I prefer this approach over having that script in my index.html that should be clean. Have a look at this:
https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga/blob/master/src/utils/loadGA.js

Comment: @MatanBobi But I cannot see any script inside the head tag after initializing ReactGA in my root component. But when I initialize GTM in my root component, then I can see the script tag with the code in the head tag. Is it okay to just initialize ReactGA with my id in the root component, as I have no other way to test?

Comment: Not sure I'm following @ZeeshanSafdar.. What's not working for you at the moment?  I believe that these questions are better asked in a new question if you think something isn't working :)

Comment: It is not recommend to use `ga-react` anymore. It is not maintained since Universal Analytics was deprecated on July 2023 and the Github repo is now archived.

Answer (score 31):

If you prefer not to use a package this is how it can work in a react application. 
Add the "gtag" in index.html

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<script>
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag() {
                dataLayer.push(arguments);
            }
            gtag("js", new Date());

            gtag("config", "<GA-PROPERTYID>");
        </script>
```

In the submit action of the login form, fire off the event

```
window.gtag("event", "login", {
            event_category: "access",
            event_label: "login"
        });
```

Comment: Any ideas how to gather all the information you need to pass to the gtag, which is scattered all across the app? It's easy to pass hardcoded string but when you have dynamic data (let's say for logged in users) that's complicated.

Comment: @mkupiniak I would use a "closure" for that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures. It should allow you to capture state data from all over in the client and send it when firing the event.

Answer (score 25):

Without using a package this is how I would do it:

In your `index.js` (in the `render` method):

```
    {/* Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics */}
    <script
      async
      src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=YOUR_TRACKING_ID"
    />
    <script>{injectGA()}</script>
```

And outside the class:

```
const injectGA = () => {
  if (typeof window == 'undefined') {
    return;
  }
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag() {
    window.dataLayer.push(arguments);
  }
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'YOUR_TRACKING_ID');
};
```

Answer (score 7):

There are 2 types of Google Analytics properties: Universal Analytics (`UA-xxxxxxxxx-x`) which is [deprecated with the end of life on 2023.07.01](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11583528?hl=en) and Google Analytics 4 property (`G-xxxxxxxxxx`) which is the replacement.

[`react-ga`](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga) was popular for Universal Analytics but [the maintainer doesn't plan to update it](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga/issues/460#issuecomment-820369771) (related issues: [1](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga/issues/460), [2](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga/issues/493), [3](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga/issues/520)) and it had maintenance issues ([1](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga/issues/523)). [`react-ga4`](https://github.com/PriceRunner/react-ga4) and [`ga-4-react`](https://github.com/unrealmanu/ga-4-react) popped up as replacements but since these are similar wrappers you're at the mercy of the maintainers to implement and support all functionality.

The simplest way to get started is to follow [Google's guide](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/install): include `gtag` on the page and use it as `window.gtag`. This method works for both old and new tags and there's even TypeScript support via `@types/gtag.js`. The script can be loaded async [as recommended](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs#alternative_async_tag).

`index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- ... -->

    <script
      async
      src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-xxxxxxxxxx" >
    </script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());
      gtag('config', 'G-xxxxxxxxxx')
    </script>

    <!-- ... -->
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- ... -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Keep in mind that Google Analytics does automatic page tracking, but this will not work for every use case. For example, `hash` and `search` parameter changes are [not tracked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73362255/2771889). This can lead to a lot of confusion. For example, when using [`HashRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/hash-router) or anchor links the navigation will not be tracked. To have full control over page view tracking you can [disable automatic tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/pages#disable_pageview_measurement). See for a detailed explanation: [The Ultimate Guide to Google Analytics (UA & GA4) on React (Or Anything Else](https://csaba-apagyi.medium.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-google-analytics-ua-ga4-on-react-or-anything-else-ec9dc84c0211)

Manual page tracking: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63249329/2771889

You can see this working in [cra-typescript-starter](https://github.com/thisismydesign/cra-typescript-starter) where I'm also setting the tag from an env var.

Comment: Most up to date answer since Universal Analytics was deprecated on July 2023.

Answer (score 4):

One other great library that you can check is [redux-beacon](https://github.com/rangle/redux-beacon).

It gets integrated very easily with react/redux application and has a great documentation for it. ReactGA is good too but with redux-beacon, you won't clutter your app code with google analytics code as it works via its own middleware.

Comment: This is the better solution *if* you're using `redux` in the application (which you probably should be doing). It's better to treat your analytics as an externality, rather than integral to your code. `redux-beacon` allows you to configure connections to _multiple_ analytics services based on redux actions, avoiding coupling your code to your analytics provider.

Answer (score 4):

**Escape the analytics code with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`**

First you have of course to share the header code to all pages, e.g. as asked at: [React js do common header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38510111/react-js-do-common-header)

Then, this Next.js answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24588369/895245 gives a good working code that should also work outside of Next.js. It escapes the analytics code with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`:

```
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-47867706-3"></script>
  <script
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
      __html: `window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'UA-47867706-3', { page_path: window.location.pathname });
`,
    }}
  />
```

where you should replace `UA-47867706-3` with your own code.

This code is exactly the code that Google gives, but with the following modification: we added the:

```
{ page_path: window.location.pathname }
```

to `gtag('config'` for it to be able to get the visited path, since this is a JavaScript SPA.

This generates the desired output on the browser:

```
<script async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-47867706-3"></script><script>window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'UA-47867706-3', { page_path: window.location.pathname });
</script>
```

The only other divergence from the exact code given by Google is the `async=""` vs `async`, but both of those are equivalent in HTML since it is a boolean attribute, see also: [What's the proper value for a checked attribute of an HTML checkbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851868/whats-the-proper-value-for-a-checked-attribute-of-an-html-checkbox/24588369#24588369)

Escaping with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is necessary because otherwise React interprets the code inside `script` a JSX and that fails with:

```
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected "}"

  21 |           <script>
  22 |             window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
> 23 |             function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
     |                                                      ^
  24 |             gtag('js', new Date());
  25 |
  26 |             gtag('config', 'UA-47867706-3');
```

I wish they would just automatically escape stuff inside `script` for us.

Finally to get page switches, you also have to track that with more code, see the Next.js answer mentioned above for an example.

Related: [Adding script tag to React/JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx)

Tested on react 17.0.2, next.js 10.2.2.

Comment: Do not follow such approaches
`dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is React’s replacement for using innerHTML in the browser DOM but setting HTML from code is risky because it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack.

Comment: @NevetsKuro there's no risk when injecting a string literal like this, only if you have user input variables.

Comment: Yes my bad. It is for the case for user input only. 
But you need to mention that in this solution, as React keeps popping this as a bug/warning.
Ref: https://pragmaticwebsecurity.com/articles/spasecurity/react-xss-part2.html

Answer (score 0):

I suggest embedding the [Segment script](https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-react) into your `index.html`, use the analytics library that is accessible on the `window` object, and add tracking calls onto React’s event handlers:

```
export default class SignupButton extends Component {
  trackEvent() {
    window.analytics.track('User Signup');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.trackEvent}>
        Signup with Segment today!
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

I’m the maintainer of https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-react. I recommend checking it out if you want to solve this problem by using one singular API to manage your customer data, and be able to integrate into any other analytics tool (we support over 250+ destinations) without writing any additional code.

Comment: Looks like this library is deprecated and no longer supported. This must be the replacement: https://github.com/segmentio/analytics.js.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at google's site https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs,

you could also add Google Analytics using this function:

```js
const enableGA = () => {
  !function(A,n,g,u,l,a,r){A.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l,A[l]=A[l]||function(){
  (A[l].q=A[l].q||[]).push(arguments)},A[l].l=+new Date,a=n.createElement(g),
  r=n.getElementsByTagName(g)[0],a.src=u,r.parentNode.insertBefore(a,r)
  }(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
}
```

This way you don't need an external library, and it's pretty quick to setup.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install react-ga
```

Add it to App.js

```
const TRACKING_ID = "G-YOUR ANALYTICS CODE";
ReactGA.initialize(TRACKING_ID);
```

If you're using react-router-dom you need to catch page switches, use this hook.

```
  function usePageViews() {
  let location = useLocation();
  useEffect(() => {
    ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname + location.search);
  }, [location]);
}
```

And call it inside your function

```
usePageViews();
```

Complete example :

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Navigate, useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';
import Homepage from "./pages/homepage";
import ReactGA from "react-ga";


const TRACKING_ID = "G-9N3HQMQXJT";
ReactGA.initialize(TRACKING_ID);

function usePageViews() {
    let location = useLocation();
    useEffect(() => {
        ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname + location.search);
    }, [location]);
}
function App() {
    usePageViews();
    return (
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Navigate replace to="/homepage" />} />

                <Route path="/homepage" element={<Homepage />} />
                {/* Other Routes /*}


            </Routes>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```