# Add google analytics gtag code snippet in React

Tags: reactjs, gtag.js

I have the following Google Analytics (gtag) code to be added in my React project.
I am trying to add it in render() method. But its not working. How to resolve it. Thanks.

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=#######"></script>
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', '#########');
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: add inside componentDidMount lifecycle method

Comment: You should put it in your `index.html` file.

Comment: There is no index.html currently in my react project. Should I create one under public folder - /public/index.html and the code snippet there. Will it work ? I am not sure if there is any other way for especially for React applications.

Comment: There is an index.html file for every React project under the public folder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding Google Analytics to React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49279820/adding-google-analytics-to-react)

Answer (score -1):

You can use [React-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) package to Manipulate Document Head