# Google Analytics 4 with React

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, react-ga

I've been trying to use react-ga package with google analytics 4 in my app. The measurement id doesn't work with it and there is no tracking code in google analytics 4 I can use. Please, I need help!

```
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
const trackingId = 'G-XXXXXXXXXX'; // UA-XXXXXXXXX-X isn't available in GA4
ReactGA.initialize(trackingId, options);
ReactGA.pageview(page);
```

Comment: react-ga4 is available now : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ga4

Comment: thanks, @w3uiguru for the link +1

Comment: Why not just use the Google Analytics 4 tracking code?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The code you entered in the example, `G-XXXXXXXXXX` , refers to the new Google Analytics 4 which, being a different system from the previous one and does not work (yet) with that plugin.

So you can follow the instructions mentioned in the answer of @Shyam or (and I suggest you because GA4 is too unripe at the moment) create a Universal Analytics type Property and use its ID (UA-XXXXX-X) with the plugin you indicated. You can find it by clicking on `Show advanced options` (when you create a new property):

[image]

Comment: Currently there aren't API or SDK for GA4.

Comment: I am having the white page router issue when adding GA
could it be because am using GA4?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64644897/google-analytics-with-react-and-react-router

Comment: I replied to your message (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64644897/google-analytics-with-react-and-react-router) so as not to leave it unresolved.

Comment: UA is now fully deprecated

Comment: No, UA properties will stop processing data in July 2024 for 360 properties.

Answer (score 24):

.. react-ga does not work with Google Analytics 4.

Use ga-4-react instead: https://github.com/unrealmanu/ga-4-react

```
npm i ga-4-react
```

By adding

```
import GA4React from "ga-4-react";
const ga4react = new GA4React("G-XXXXXXXXXX");
ga4react.initialize().then().catch()
```

Thanks to the comments, I updated this post a little. I added a try/catch (for preventing AddBlocker Crashes) and a setTimeout.
The ".catch()"-Methode should be trailed to "ga4react.initialize()" to handle errors inside the initialize promise.
Analytics Systems should not be loaded at the beginning of a Page load. React apps are mostly single page applications, so this code is only loaded once (if needed you can replace "4000" milliseconds to "0").

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import GA4React from "ga-4-react";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));

try {
  setTimeout(_ => {
    const ga4react = new GA4React("G-XXXXXXXXXX");
    ga4react.initialize().catch(err => console.error(err));
  }, 4000);
} catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
}

// G-XXXXXXXXXX is your MESS-ID from Google Analytics
```

How to find the MESS-ID in Google Analytics 4 (new) properties =>
https://analyticshelp.io/blog/google-analytics-property-tracking-id/

Comment: I will mention that doing this typically crashes the app if someone has an adblocker. If the request fails, `ERROR: Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js”.` ... but this code is a great starting place.

Comment: The link is invalid

Answer (score 13):

Background: There are 2 types of Google Analytics properties: Universal Analytics (`UA-xxxxxxxxx-x`) which is [deprecated with the end of life on 2023.07.01](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11583528?hl=en) and Google Analytics 4 property (`G-xxxxxxxxxx`) which is the replacement.

[`react-ga`](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga) was popular for Universal Analytics but [the maintainer doesn't plan to update it](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga/issues/460#issuecomment-820369771) (related issues: [1](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga/issues/460), [2](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga/issues/493), [3](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga/issues/520)) and it had maintenance issues ([1](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga/issues/523)). [`react-ga4`](https://github.com/PriceRunner/react-ga4) and [`ga-4-react`](https://github.com/unrealmanu/ga-4-react) popped up as replacements but since these are similar wrappers you're at the mercy of the maintainers to implement and support all functionality.

The simplest way to get started is to follow [Google's guide](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/install): include `gtag` on the page and use it as `window.gtag`. This method works for both old and new tags and there's even TypeScript support via `@types/gtag.js`. The script can be loaded async [as recommended](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs#alternative_async_tag).

`index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- ... -->

    <script
      async
      src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-xxxxxxxxxx" >
    </script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());
      gtag('config', 'G-xxxxxxxxxx')
    </script>

    <!-- ... -->
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- ... -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Keep in mind that Google Analytics does automatic page tracking, but this will not work for every use case. For example, `hash` and `search` parameter changes are [not tracked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73362255/2771889). This can lead to a lot of confusion. For example, when using [`HashRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/hash-router) or anchor links the navigation will not be tracked. To have full control over page view tracking you can [disable automatic tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/pages#disable_pageview_measurement). See for a detailed explanation: [The Ultimate Guide to Google Analytics (UA & GA4) on React (Or Anything Else](https://csaba-apagyi.medium.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-google-analytics-ua-ga4-on-react-or-anything-else-ec9dc84c0211)

Manual page tracking: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63249329/2771889

You can see this working in [cra-typescript-starter](https://github.com/thisismydesign/cra-typescript-starter) where I'm also setting the tag from an env var.

Comment: Great answer, that should be much higher up

Answer (score 9):

Google Analytics 4 is different from pre ga 4.
react-ga does not support this yet.
https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga/issues/460

You may need to do this manually
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9325020
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/tag-guide

Comment: As mentioned in the issue, `react-ga` is in passive maintenance and therefore it is currently unclear if it will ever support GA 4 properties properly. However, there is a new library [`ga-4-react`](https://github.com/unrealmanu/ga-4-react) which is specifically made for GA 4 and looks promising.

Comment: react-ga4 is available now https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ga4

Answer (score 7):

`react-ga` does not work with GA-4. I will also say that in `react-ga`'s issues, the owner has said that unless someone creates a PR, he does not intend to add GA-4 support. The project is also not well maintained anymore.

You could theoretically create a universal property in the GA admin dashboard for backwards compatibility with earlier GA versions. At that point, you could use `react-ga`, but your best bet is to use `ga-4-react` instead: https://github.com/unrealmanu/ga-4-react

```js
npm i ga-4-react
```

...

I will add on to @TG___ 's answer. The code he provided in his answer is a good start, but I will mention that it typically crashes the app if someone has an adblocker (adblocker blocks analytics request endpoints, no error handling, etc).

> ERROR: Loading failed for the  with source “https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js”

... Below is an expansion of his code to use the promise that `ga4react.initialize()` returns. This way, you can essentially detect whether the script didn't load and hence derive if the user has an adblocker that's preventing the GA script from loading. In my example code, I just ignore it and load the app... in other scenarios, I suppose you could invoke a modal to tell them to disable it (of course, that would come with extra code).

By adding

```js
 await ga4react.initialize()
```

to your index.js in src GA-4 will start and add a pageview. Works also with react-router without adding any code. By the Promise (await) you have to wrap it into an async-function (below as a closure).

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

const ga4react = new GA4React("G-XXXXXXXXXX");

(async _ => {
  
await ga4react.initialize()
.then(res => console.log("Analytics Success."))
.catch(err => console.log("Analytics Failure."))
.finally(() => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Router>
        <App />
      </Router>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
});
})();
```

Answer (score 4):

You may want to have a look at this package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ga4

It offers the same API as the normal react-ga. So just change your package name from react-ga to react-ga4 and it should work.

Tried it myself and it works great!

Comment: Is same measurement id will work ?

Comment: No, you need to create a new property for Analytics 4. The old package (react-ga) works with Universal Analytics-Properties and react-ga4 with GA4-Properties.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 versions of google analytics

1. Google Analytics 4 ( the updated one )
2. Universal Analytics ( the older one )

react-ga works fine with Universal Analytics as it takes the Tracking Id to initialize the connection between react and google analytics.

The problem is that whenever a user creates a new account, GA4 is being offered by default. But the GA4 doesn't have the Tracking Id that is required. GA4 has the Measurement ID but the react-ga doesn't want it. So we need the Tracking Id in order to set up the react-ga in our react app.

So the solution is, **"Either downgrade from GA4 to Universal Analytics or Create a property that contains both of them as in GA4 and Universal Analytics together."**

I would recommend watching the following videos:

GA4 vs Universal Analytics: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y6WxUEk6clw

How to downgrade or keep both: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jRmb0jMNUKU

Answer (score 2):

You probably know about the `react-ga` npm package but the sad news is, it does not work with the latest Google Analytics 4 version. It works with the old `UA-0000-01` tags that was associated with `Universal Analytics` , but not with the G-XXXXXX tags that is `Google Analytics 4`. Universal Analytics will stop working in the near future.

**Solution:**
To tackle this issue you should start using `react-ga4` npm package which supports Google Analytics 4.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ga4

**Note:**
Universal analytics properties will stop collecting data starting july 1, 2023. it’s recommended that you create a google analytics 4 property instead.
Reference: [Google Analytics Support](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11583528?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't specifically answer the question. But, you can create a Firebase web app to log events. Worked for me as a workaround to get data into Google Analytics as it does not seem like you can create a UA identifier to me anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Adblock. Disable your Ad Block extension.

It took me quiet a few long and painful hours to realize that the problem was with an Ad Block chrome extension.

Once I disabled the extension, the events started to trigger.