# Unable to see event_category in Google Analytics 4

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics-4

I am new to GA and I have integrated my react app with Google Analytics 4 and sent custom events to analytics like this
`ReactGA.event({category: 'abc', action: 'xyz'})`

This created an event in GA4 but when I am exploring events and reports I couldn't find anywhere the metric/dimension named **event_category**. Please tell me how can I see the event_category of my events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have exactly the same setup, and 'category' does indeed show up as 'event_category' in GA4.

There are many ways to view the event and its parameters. The easiest is perhaps: Reports>Engagement>Events. A dropdown at the top-left allows you to choose your event ('Enquire' here). Then a panel at the right has a dropdown showing all of the parameters; event_category shows up there.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think ReactGA is applicable for GA4? I glanced at their git repo and it looks like it's made for UA. GA4 is different. It has a different event model, different custom dimensions model, different tracking endpoint, different tracking id format. GA4 doesn't have a native concept of category or action.

You're trying to use a UA library to send GA4 events. Try this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ga4

Also, read this answer: [Google Analytics 4 with React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64623059/google-analytics-4-with-react) GA4 is still raw, despite the eagerness with which Google pushes it. We normally suggest sticking to UA for a few more years.

Comment: Hi, I am using react-ga4 library only. Sorry not to mention it earlier

Comment: well then why would you look for `event_category` if the dimension you're setting is `categoty`?