# How to prevent Header from rendering on Login screen?

Tags: reactjs

I am using ReactJS and I have a login screen. Only after you login should the user should be shown the header. Right now, the header is appearing on the login screen, which I don't want. How do I get rid of it?

I've tried wrapping the Login path in its own `Router`, but that doesn't help. The header still renders. The code below is in `index.js`. That's where all my routing is done and calling other components.

```
const routing = (
  <div>
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
    <Router>
      <Header>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/landingpage/videos" exact component={Videos} />
        </Switch>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/landingpage/contact-us" exact component={Contact} />
        </Switch>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/landingpage/stats/" exact component={Stats} />
        </Switch>
      </Header>
    </Router>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Why did you use `<Header>` in routing? Please use it in other components: `Videos`, `Contact`...

Comment: ```Header``` is a shared component that all the other pages will have. Why would I re-render it on every page? It would make more sense to render ```Header``` once and then render the actual ```Videos```, ```Contact``` page components.

Comment: When you go to every page with route, the whole page should be rendered. To prevent rerendering `Header`, you should not use route to go to every page or it's not a single-page application.

Comment: Sounds like what you're saying is similar to the Answer, that I have misconceptions. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Good Luck! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some misconceptions in your code, try with:

```
const routing = (
    <div>
      <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
          <Route path="/landingpage/videos" exact render={(props) => <Header><Videos /></Header>} />
          <Route path="/landingpage/contact-us" exact  render={(props) => <Header><Contact /></Header>} />
          <Route path="/landingpage/stats/" exact  render={(props) => <Header><Stats /></Header>} />        
        </Switch>
    </div>
  );
```

`<Router />` renders all matching routes, while `<Switch />` render only first matching route.

Additionally, your scaffolding should be wrapping every single component with a route (there are different patterns to manage that, this is only one)

Comment: I will try this soon! What do you mean my "scaffolding". Not familiar with that term.

Comment: _Scaffolding_ is refers to _how elements are nested_

Comment: And it's better to import and render Header in each page (Videos, Contact etc) It will make code much cleaner as @Antonio Cholony suggested.

Comment: Alright, it works! I had to wrap the entire ```<Switch>``` in ```<Router>```.

Comment: @MykolaPrymak I was looking at this StackOverflow post before I decided to post my own: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38510111/react-js-do-common-header. This post seems to suggest the opposite.

Comment: This is not the opposite, just another pattern

Comment: @McFloofenbork I agree, that this technique is also can be used.

Comment: That's weird because I followed it and it did not work for me. Is that pattern dependent on having browserHistory?

Comment: Nope, simply header is outside routing in other example.